# change my software language using button press.all the keys are getting translated except two keys sharing same page of the button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `angular js` and trying to change my language. I have a `json` from where translation keys are getting fetched. But when I am trying to change my language using a button press all the keys are changed except two keys which are generating manually from `js`.

```
$rootScope.PreferredLanguage = $scope.Language;                              
$translate.use($rootScope.PreferredLanguage);  
document.getElementById("adduser").innerText = $filter('translate')('Users.profile_of') + ' ' + $scope.TooltipUserFullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, may be since you are assigning to/ using `document.getElementById("adduser").innerText` it is not working. You can try running digest using $applyAsync.

And, I will suggest instead of below code, 
    document.getElementById("adduser").innerText = $filter('translate')('Users.profile_of') + ' ' + $scope.TooltipUserFullName;

you can use `Users.profile_of | translate` in html and have the binding.

Example:

```
<div ng-if="toggleTheModelWhenUserClicksOnOtherElement">
  <div id="adduser">{{'Users.profile_of' | translate}} TooltipUserFullName</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.